# Error code 1 cordova plugin file transfer android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a problem on cordova (android), when I try to download a file (a .zip exactly), It always occured a error code 1.
The url downloads well on my computer.
Here is the code :

```
    let fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
      url = encodeURI(url);

      fileTransfer.download(
        url,
        cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory,
        function(entry) {
          console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
        },
        function(error) {
          console.log('download error source ' + error.source);
          console.log('download error target ' + error.target);
          console.log('upload error code is ' + error.code);
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: Error code as per plugin documentation is "NOT_FOUND_ERR"
 which means the requested resource is not found. Ensure the resource is available and also ensure you have added Cordova whitelist plugin to make CORS request

Comment: It wasn't the problem, but thank you for taking time to help me

Comment: Glad it worked. Looks like not found error meant file not found in device to write I guess.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The error was that I forgot to specify the name of the file when it will be downloaded on the device, I didn't know I had to specify that.
So here is the corrected code (modifications at lign 6) :

```
  let fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
  url = encodeURI(url);

  fileTransfer.download(
    url,
    cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory+'whatever.png',
    function(entry) {
      console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log('download error source ' + error.source);
      console.log('download error target ' + error.target);
      console.log('upload error code is ' + error.code);
    });
```

Comment: very nice catch!

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure path of target file ( downloaded file ) is valid.
2. Make sure target file name is valid.
3. Make sure download file path is valid.

Code 1 corresponds to `FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR`